# dependency cycle lucid -- oneiric

Tags: 10.04, package-management, 11.10

I am trying to install php5.3.6 on Lucid Lynx using oneiric repository to have everything in place on the ubuntu way and avoid manual package compiling.

I got the following error:
Couldn't configure multiarch-support for libdb5.1, probably a dependency cycle.

The problem is libdb5.1 is depending on multiarch-support but multiarch support wants to install libdb5.1.

command used: sudo apt-get -t oneiric install php5 php5-common libapache2-mod-php5
When i try to install multiarch-support same way it says the same thing.

How should i solve this?
The reaason for this is to change between versions of softwares on a clearer way without building custom deb packages from source.

---

**Update 1**

Yes, I am aware of this but i am just trying different scenarios because some of our development sites needed `php5.2.x` before that I installed from karmic repository on ubuntu lucid lynx and worked perfectly.

So  I just wanted to test what if I want the most fresh version from oneiric repository.
I hoped there is something than compiling it manually from source that I also tested and worked perfectly.

Comment: The Oneiric repositories are not yet stable.  You should not be upgrading from Lucid -> Oneiric directly, but rather upgrading to Natty first.  Having said this, those repos for Oneiric are not stable,  so you should not upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

First I would not advise you to use a repository which is not meant for that series (maverick, lucid, oneiric etc). It can result in lot of problems and cryptic problems.

Do you specifically need the PHP version 5.3.6? Will 5.3.2 work? Being a minor version it should not be of much problem

If yes then you should do an apt-get update

> sudo apt-get update

and then do an upgrade to install PHP 5.3 from the official repositories.

Since 10.04 is LTS, so it is supported even now.

The package `php 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9` was [uploaded in Official repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/php5/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9) on 2nd May 2011 by Steve Beattie.